# how to drop rows based on other column only if has multiple different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**What I have?**

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     id    value 
0    0       5
1    0       5
2    0       6
3    1       7   
4    1       7
```

**What I want to get?**

I want to drop all the rows with id that has more than **one** different value. in the example above I want to drop all the rows with id = 0

```
      id    value
3      1      7
4      1      7
```

**What I have tried?**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'value':[5,5,6,7,7]})
print(df)

id_list = df['id'].tolist() 
id_set = set(id_list)

for id in id_set:
    temp_list = df.loc[df['id'] == id,'value'].tolist()
    s = set(temp_list)
    if len(s) > 1:
        df = df.loc[df['id'] != id]
```

it works, but it ugly and inefficient

**There is a better pytonic way using pandas methods?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for number of unique values to Series, so possible compare and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
print (df)
   id  value
3   1      7
4   1      7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Try this code #        
import pandas as pd
id1 = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1])
value = pd.Series([5,5,6,7,7])
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':id1,'value':value})
datag = data.groupby('id')
# to delete rows,that id have different values
datadel = []
for i in set(data.id):
    if len(set(datag.get_group(i)['value'])) != 1:
        datadel.extend(data.loc[data["id"] == i].index.tolist())
         
data.drop(datadel, inplace = True) 
print(data)
```